# Publishing Visual Studio 2017 multi-project VSIX to the marketplace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to port my [Extended Visio Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NikolayBelyh.ExtendedVisioAddinProject) visual studio extension (multi-project template with custom wizard) to Visual Studio 2017.

I followed the steps for migrating extension, as clarified in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017

It builds and installs/works locally fine ("works on my machine") but the visual studio [site](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/upload/view) refuses to accept it, giving dumb error message **Invalid Template File in VSIX**. May it be connected somehow to recent migration of "visual studio gallery" into marketplace (does it work at all) - is it me, or them? :)

Should I do something differently for VS 2017, if it's a multi-project template (the multi-project template for 2010-2015 seems to upload fine)?

Or maybe somebody can give me a link/reference to a working source code for **multi-project** template for Visual Studio **2017** (v3), that can be **successfully uploaded to visual studio gallery**?

Full source code is available on [github](https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/tree/master/VSIX), including [manifest](https://github.com/nbelyh/VisioPanelAddinVSTO/blob/master/VSIX/manifest_2017/source.extension.vsixmanifest), and all templates (files with .2017 suffix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself, for those who may fall into the same trap :) The problem appeared to be **missing `<Icon>` element in one of the child projects**.

After Microsoft migrated the gallery hub to Marketplace, it started go give you much better diagnostics on failures, helping to address those sort of things - now at least it is possible to figure out what the marketplace didn't like in your extension exactly :)

After adding `<Icon>` the extension was successfully [published](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NikolayBelyh.ExtendedVisioAddinProject2017)